# FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING filters letters that shouldn't be filtered

Tags: php, security, prepared-statement

I'm using filter to clean my strings before i use prepared statements

```
 filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'x', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING )
```

the problem is that I'm from Lithuania and here we have some pretty weird letters like ą č ę ė į š ų ū and I need those unfiltered, i can't find another filter FILTER_SANITIZE_ that would work, is there any? and if not is there another function that does this the way i need?

Comment: What is your intent with the sanitizing? To stop SQL injections, or XSS injections later? The prepared statements should take care of the SQL injection.

Comment: i filter so input goes to database clean so i don't have to worry when i want to display it, it's more for XSS part

Comment: I send it to DB as is then use http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php to display it on your page, with `ENT_QUOTES`.

Comment: so what's the use of filter_input? what's the best practice, to do as i'm dealing with it or using htmlspecialchars?

Comment: i do it this way because HTML part of the application looks clean

Comment: I never filter the data going to DB. Once you filter you lose the original content forever. I filter on output and have an approve/disapprove. If it is complete non-sense I disapprove and it wont display.

Comment: this raises one more problem, i've been using if(filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )) to check for valid email format, isn't it best practice to use server-side validation with client-side js validation too? since it's possible to turn javascript off people could input anything and it's not good for registration, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Always validate server side, client side is just a nicer experience for user so they don't get bounced around. Data can always be manipulated though before it gets to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: Don't filter.

HTML encode when you output to an HTML page.

e.g.
`&` becomes `&amp;`, `<` becomes `&lt;`.

Use [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to do this.

HTML code isn't dangerous in your database - it's only dangerous when user input is output unencoded.

Since you're already using prepared statements, you're already protected against SQLi (assuming there's not any query concatenation going on anywhere of course, for example within any SPs you are calling).

Comment: 2nd'd, with this approach you don't run the risk of loosing user inputted data. The output filter can always be adjusted if a problem is discovered down the line